# How to declare/define a class with template template parameters without using an extra template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

Consider the following use of template template parameters...

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename X>
class A
{
    X _t;
public:
    A(X t)
        :_t(t)
    {
    }
    X GetValue()
    {
        return _t;
    }
};

template <typename T, template <typename T> class C >
class B
{
    C<T> _c;
public:
    B(T t)
        :_c(t)
    {
    }
    T GetValue()
    {
        return _c.GetValue();
    }
};

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    B<int, A> b(10);
    cout<<b.GetValue();
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way by which the template parameter T can be removed? For example is there a way to make the following work?

```
//Does not compile
template <template <typename T> class C >
class B
{
    C _c;
public:
    B(T t)
        :_c(t)
    {
    }
    T GetValue()
    {
        return _c.GetValue();
    }
};

int main()
{
    B< A<int> > b(10);
    cout<<b.GetValue();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you're after X, as well as A, in your code.

The usual pattern is to have

```
template<typename C>
struct B
{
   C c;
};
```

and then, inside classes eligible for substitution:

```
template<typename X>
class A
{
   typedef X type_name;
   X t;
};
```

Then you can access the template parameter using `C::type_name`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer though I eventually discovered this myself. I was in the process of editing the question and posting my work around but apparently I had come to the right place to ask this question!

Comment: note that Sunlight's answer is better than mine, since he has understood what you want. No need to rebind like i showed you. That would only be required if you use A<int>, but occasionally have the need or A<float>. Or if the user's view is A<int>, but you use A<float> .

Comment: +1! I was searching for a way to receive a reference to any standard container, and using this way getting the type with `C::value_type` was really useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible. Note that this is a common misunderstanding: `A<int>` is not a class template anymore! So it would not fit to a template-template parameter, but would have to be accepted using a type-parameter:

```
template<typename C>
struct B {
    C c;
};

B< A<int> > b;
```

Your way of using a separate parameter is alright.

If you want to accept `A<int>` but want to re-bind it to another parameter, you can use this pattern, also used by standard-allocators:

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
    template<typename U>
    struct rebind {
        typedef A<U> type;
    };
};

template<typename C>
struct B {
    typename C::template rebind<float>::type c;
};

B< A<int> > b;
```

Now, `B< A<int> >::c` is of type `A<float>`. The `typename` before `C::` tells the compiler the `::type` at the end is a type and not a static non-type member. The `template` after `C::` tells the compiler the `rebind<float>` is a template instantiation, and not a comparision.

Comment: Ok cool! Nice answer but unfortunately there can only be one answer and I think @sunlight posted his solution earlier to you. I have upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with:

```
template <typename C >
struct B
{
    C c;
};

int main()
{
    B< A<int> > b;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My bad, the problem was not fully specified. Now it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can nest parameters.  That is, the value of a parameter can itself be parameterized.

```
template <typename X>
struct A
{
  X t;
};

template <typename  C>
struct B
{
  C c;
};

int main()
{
  B< A<int> > b;
  return 0;
}
```

In this example, the declaration of `b` in `main()` creates a specialization of `A` using `int` as the parameter, then it creates a specialization of `B` using `A<int>` as the parameter.  Thus, in the specialization of `B`, `C` is `A<int>`.

Comment: Your solution is correct according to the original question but I have added some details I missed the first time. Thanks.